# How to implement middleware auth in controller without loop redirection?

Tags: laravel

I try to se middleware('auth') in a controller, I put this code in my controller (userController.php)

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

And my routes are

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('home', [UserController::class,'home'])->name('home');
Route::get('login', [UserController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [UserController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::get('logout', [UserController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

What I hope is that if I try to get /home I will reach login, then if login is ok I'd arrive home page.
But what I get is a infinite redirect loop!!!

I tried

```
$this->middleware('auth')->except(['login']);
```

But the problem goes on.
I'm using the default middleware('auth') of Laravel (10)
Where is my error?
Thanks

Comment: close right `->except(['login'])`

Comment: This is an error wirting the question, my code sintax is ok. This is not the problem.

Comment: You don't have enough info to answer the question here, but you should just declare your middleware in the route file, especially in this case where you only want it on one route. Also don't forget to clear cache after changes. `artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Yes, I know I can use middleware in route too, but I want to know every way to use it, in order to understand how middleware works in Laravel..

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass route name instead of URI, Route name seems similar for both get and post login routes, change post route name to something else like `loginSubmit` and try.

```
$this->middleware('auth')->except('loginSubmit')
```

Reference from [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#controller-middleware).